# OpenGL ES clickable objects

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have created a OpenGL view with 6 different objects. Is there a way to make these objects clickable and call a method as any other UIControl in iOS?

If so how is this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered before on SO:

[iphone-opengl-es-detecting-if-you-have-tapped-a-object-cube-on-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365856/iphone-opengl-es-detecting-if-you-have-tapped-a-object-cube-on-screen)

[iphone-openggl-es-detecting-clicks-on-a-primitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4349440/iphone-openggl-es-detecting-clicks-on-a-primitive)

I got to these by **googling "ios openGL ES click on object"**